# what's the difference in effect of backgrounding vs forking?

Tags: python, daemon, background-process, init

**Goal**:  Create a long running process from a python script.

I started with [a simple unix/linux daemon in Python](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python).  But, then I also created an init script that just sents the python script (with a while loop) into the background like this:

```
python test.py &
```

I'm wondering what the difference, in effect, is between the two of these methods?

*note: I understand that one creates a child process, and the other doesn't.  My question revolves more around the effect.*

Comment: which of the two do you think does not create a child process?

Comment: It accomplishes the same thing effectively.  With the `&`, the shell is doing the forking, when you do it in python, *you* (script) are doing the forking instead of the shell, but they end up to be almost the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same thing. The only difference is the python daemon *should* set the parent process which means if you kill the parent process the child should die too.